# How to release unused occupied memory by a program in C#

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

I have developed a program to read write HID device with specified product id and vendor id (pid and vid). This is the [library](http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/):

It's working perfectly except one problem. In a timer tick event I am checking whether the device is connected or not. Timer tick duration is 1000 ms. The code is below:

```
if (_connectionTester.IsDeviceConnected())
{
    connectionStatusPictureBox.Image = Globals.Resources.GreenCircleImage;
    HIDGlobals.Connected = true;
}
else
{
    connectionStatusPictureBox.Image = Globals.Resources.RedCircleImage;
    HIDGlobals.Connected = false;
}
```

and the `IsDeviceConnected` function is:

```
 public bool IsDeviceConnected()
 {
     return _usb.getDeviceList()
         .Any(d => d.Contains(HIDGlobals.VID + "&" + HIDGlobals.PID));
 }
```

The problem is with the elapses of time it increases the memory usage. When I first start the software the memory usage is 33.6 MB (in task manager memory column). After 10 minutes it becomes 38.7 MB. After 5-6 hours it becomes GB.

It's such an application which will run for 8-9 hours. Is there any way to release the memory? I have tried Garbage Collector `GC.Collect()`.

But it didn't help. Could anyone help in this regards?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Memory use growing into the GB range would appear to indicate a leak somewhere, so that's what you need to identify & address

Comment: Typically GC utilized unused memory very good. Code you've provided is insufficient to deduce where memory leak can be. You have to use some memory profilers to locate it.

Comment: Could it be the result of `GetDeviceList` that needs to be disposed?

Comment: To @AlexK. point there's no special magic `CleanUpLeaks()`  method. You need to figure out what's being allocated. I would *start* by grabbing a memory dump and open it up with Windbg and do a `!Dumpheap -stat`. Anything else is shooting in the dark

Comment: Eliminate the variables: is the problem `IsDeviceConnected` or the pictures? I have suspicion that it might be the library that is leaking the memory. Took quick look & the source code seems quite a fishy.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisEelmaa. Have a look at hiltOn's comments on the library site: http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/ In particular, check his comments about there being a memory leak in *"CT_SetupDiGetClassDevs () called from GetDevices()"*

Comment: Yeah, I think, I need to check the library first. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Every call Globals.Resources.GreenCircleImage creates new image. You must Dispose every image you are not using anymore or you will have memory leaks.

Two approaches:

1) You can create image instances on application start. And destroy them on application finish.

2) You need to dispose image you are replacing.

Approach 1) is better